# Program to print all possible outcomes

Tags: python

```
import random AR=[20,30,40,50,60,70]
FROM = random.randint(1,3)
TO = random.randint(2,4)
for k in range (FROM,TO+1):
            print(AR[K], end='#')
```

I am very curious to know how to print all possible output for this program.Please help.

Comment: Please correct your code to be valid (first line, and then `AR[K]`, but `K` is not defined)

Comment: Explain in words (to complement the code) what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
AR=[20,30,40,50,60,70]
for FROM in range(1,3):
    for TO in range(2,4):
        for k in range (FROM,TO+1):
            print(AR[k], end='#')
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all combination of `FROM` and `TO`, you can use `itertools.product`:

```
import random 
import itertools
AR=[20,30,40,50,60,70]
FROM = range(1,3)
TO = range(2,4)
for f,t in itertools.product(FROM, TO):
    print("from={}, to={}: ".format(f, t), end='')
    for k in range (f,t+1):
        print(AR[k], end='#')
    print()
```

Output:

```
from=1, to=2: 30#40#
from=1, to=3: 30#40#50#
from=2, to=2: 40#
from=2, to=3: 40#50#
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be range(1,4) and range(2,5) as randint includes 3 and 4 also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how

```
# import random
AR=[20,30,40,50,60,70]
for FROM in range(1,3): # instead of randomly selecting you loop through all of them
    for TO in range(2, 4):
        # FROM = random.randint(1,3)
        # TO = random.randint(2,4)
        for k in range (FROM,TO+1):
            print(AR[K], end='#')
```